# want to read data from a json onto a php file

Tags: php, json

I have the following json data:

```
{"total":{"count":68},"Messages":[

{"messageId":"32b","replyId":"b2744",
"meta":{"type":"TEXT","author":{"nickname":"Gayge","image":{"url":"https://sas.com/16.jpg","height":100,"width":100},"Category":"REGULAR"},"createdAt":1477065361,"details":{"Text":"this is just a test"},"tags":[],"Stats":{"upVoteCount":0,"replyCount":0}},

{"messageId":"33b","replyId":"b3744",
"meta":{"type":"TEXT","author":{"nickname":"jorf","image":{"url":"https://sas.com/17.jpg","height":100,"width":100},"Category":"REGULAR"},"createdAt":1477065361,"details":{"Text":"yet another test"},"tags":[],"Stats":{"upVoteCount":0,"replyCount":0}}

]}
```

I want to get that data and parse it as html like this:

```
<li id="32b">
 <p>this is just a test</p>
 <span>BY:<img src="https://sas.com/16.jpg"> <b>Gayge</b></span>
</li>
<li id="33b">
 <p>yet another test</p>
 <span>BY:<img src="https://sas.com/17.jpg"> <b>jorf</b></span>
</li>
```

I tried writing this code:

```
$str = file_get_contents("https://mypage.net/json.txt");
$data = json_decode($str,true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$lis = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
 foreach ($lis as $li) {
     $li->appendChild($p);
     $li->appendChild($span);
 }
 $final = $dom->saveHTML();
 echo $final;
fclose($open_file);
```

but from here on I am stuck and I cant figure out whats next. Help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON isn't HTML. This is way you shouldn't treat it as such (e.g. not calling `$dom->loadHTML($data);`

PHP is a great templating language, which allows for quick generation of HTML. In your specific case, I would do something like this:

```
$str = file_get_contents("https://mypage.net/json.txt");
$data = json_decode($str,true);

foreach ($data['Messages'] as $msg) {
?>
    <li id="<?= htmlspecialchars($msg['messageId']); ?>">
    <p> <?=htmlspecialchars($msg['meta']['details']['Text']); ?></p>
    <!-- The rest of your template goes here -->
    </li>
<? } ?>
```

If you do this. Be sure to escape the input strings to protect yourself against [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) using [htmlspecialchars()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Note: This approach doesn't "scale" very well, if you want to do this with many different html templates. There are dedicated HTML template engines for PHP floating around the web, [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) is a very popular one for example.

Comment: I got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' in line 22

Comment: dont you mean FOREACH?

Comment: You should try to separate the view and the logic off your app as @DaGardner said.

Comment: @CainNuke yeah, corrected the mistake... meant `foreach`